# Another "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Tags: ios, swift

> Edit 3:
>
> For other people getting this error, this is what happened here.
>
> I originally created the IBAction for the slider as "numberOfSounds".
>   I then created a class property called "numberOfSounds" and renamed
>   the IBAction to "sliderValueChanged".
>
> I expected the connection to automatically update the connection, BUT
>   IT DOESN'T. So, since I dumbly used the same name for the variable, I
>   missed the connection. See @rob accepted answer below for the telltale
>   clue.
>
> The solution was to delete the previous connection and control-drag from the slider in the storyboard to the sliderValueChanged IBAction in the ViewController.

Original question:

I'm getting this extremely common error and like many others, I'm having a hard time understanding the fix. Manipulating the slider causes a crash, which is this message:

> 2015-10-17 13:35:59.765 Test App[25969:2985698] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Test_App.ViewController numberOfSounds:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x7fc439e26740'

The breakpoint is on "numberOfSounds = Int(sender.value)".

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var numberOfSounds: Int = 0

  @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    numberOfSounds = Int(sender.value)
  }
}
```

I think I'm understanding something of the problem, being that despite numberOfSounds being a property of ViewController, its not available in the scope of sliderValueChanged.

I've read through the top 15-20 google searches for "unrecognized selector sent to instance" but still haven't found something that seems to answer the problem.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: (Adding more code)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  var numberOfSounds: Int = 0

  @IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    numberOfSounds = Int(sender.value)
  }
  @IBOutlet weak var numberOfSoundsLabel: UILabel!
  @IBAction func PlaySound(sender: UIButton) {}

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  }

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }
}
```

Edit 2: (Adding full stack trace)

> 2015-10-17 13:59:24.303 Test App[26230:3006546]
>   -[Test_App.ViewController numberOfSounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fedea730350 2015-10-17 13:59:24.313 Test
>   App[26230:3006546] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Test_App.ViewController
>   numberOfSounds:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7fedea730350'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7d7f65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x000000010c469deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x000000010a7e058d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   205   3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a72df7a
>   ___forwarding_** + 970    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a72db28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120  5   UIKit
>   0x000000010aff41fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>     6   UIKit                               0x000000010b158504
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     7   UIKit                               0x000000010b1587d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>     8   UIKit                               0x000000010b244770 -[UISlider
>   beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:] + 1083     9   UIKit
>   0x000000010b15739d -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 136     10 
>   UIKit                               0x000000010b05e894 -[UIWindow
>   _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 308  11  UIKit                               0x000000010b05f691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865     12  UIKit
>   0x000000010b011752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263  13  UIKit
>   0x000000010afecfcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693  14 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a7040a1
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   15  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a6f9fcc
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   16  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010a6f9483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867     17  CoreFoundation
>   0x000000010a6f8e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     18  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010ed6cad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  19  UIKit
>   0x000000010aff2676 UIApplicationMain + 171    20  Test App
>   0x000000010a5fc1ad main + 109     21  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010cfb092d start + 1  22  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 )

Comment: Are you sure that code exactly causes the issue and that is the exact code in your Xcode, just copied it (not retyped it?) because copying it in playground and calling the function works without any problem

Comment: @luk2302 It *should*. Its a subset of more unrelated code. Umm, let me test it real quick.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Di7pYwmN for example just works :/ as it should, there is not yet anything that could go wrong ^^

Comment: Clear any breakpoint and check the stack backtrack when you get the exception. That code as shown works

Comment: @luk2302 I added the entire ViewController including the IBOutlet and IBAction declarations too. Could the problem be a setting in the storyboard and not in the code?

Comment: @Paulw11 I updated the question with the full ViewController. Locally, I cleared all breakpoints, did a clean and rebuild. I still get the same crash when attempting to manipulate the slider in the simulator. Would sharing the entire stack trace be helpful?

Comment: Maybe. The cause of this exception is pretty straight-forward. This may be just more Swift flakiness

Comment: Open your Storyboard and use Command+F to search for "numberOfSounds:"

Comment: @Paulw11 That's not what the error message is saying.  A control in the storyboard is wired to an action named "numberOfSounds:", which is not implemented in "ViewController".  It's an action, not a property getter.

Comment: @Darren That's a useful tip. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest you removed "edit 3" from the question. If you want to expand upon the answer outlined below, then go ahead and [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you'd like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The telltale issue is the presence of the colon in `-[Test_App.ViewController numberOfSounds:]`. That means that you have something that is trying to call a method called `numberOfSounds:` with one parameter.

Assuming you don't have anything in your code that would be doing that, I would double check the outlets/actions for the slider in the "Connections Inspector" IB and make sure you don't have an action like the following:

[image]

That would result in the error message you describe. If you have any extraneous actions like the above, just click the little "x" to remove them.

--

This can happen if you once attempted to connect an action from the slider to your view controller, calling the action `numberOfSounds`, but then realized the mistake upon seeing the `IBAction` code and proceeded to delete/edit the `IBAction` function in the code, but neglecting to adjust the connection in IB, too. That's a common workflow that would result in this sort of behavior.

Comment: Ok, I have *exactly* what your clip shows. I want to understand what is happening here. I originally created the IBAction by control-dragging from the slider in the storyboard into the ViewController window. So I'm assuming the connection we're seeing here was made automatically by Xcode. Is that right?

Comment: Thank you Rob! Here's what happened. When I originally made the connection, the IBAction was named "numberOfSounds". Later, I added numberOfSounds as a class property and renamed the IBAction to better reflect its purpose. And I naively assumed that the connection was going to be renamed as well. I missed it because I reused numberOfSounds.

Comment: Yep, that would do it. Added this explanation to my answer.

Comment: Renaming your action with find and replace does not rename the link in IB. However, if you select the name of the IBAction in the editor, select "refactor" and use the refactor tool to rename the method, it changes it everywhere, including changing the link(s) in IB.